# ActiveMQ messages disappear when session is closed

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Im running a local ActiveMQ and I have one program that writes a message and another that reads it.

I run the write one first, let it end and then run the reading one.

The reading one never finds a message, but when I try to write and read in the same program (I assume its something with the session) it succeeds.

I used the code from here:
http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I was using `vm://localhost` as a broker url like they said, but it didnt work, the one that worked for me is `tcp://localhost:61616`